# Joomla: How to pick date AND time?

Tags: joomla

In a custom component, I need to enter date and time.

Joomla's standard calendar-element supports a date picker - but no time picker.

Of course, I could add a list-element with `08:00`, `08:15`, `08:30`, etc. - but hey, this is 2013...

For sure there must be a **date and time picker** around - any hints?

Comment: Joomla has not a form field type for pick a time :/ (http://docs.joomla.org/Form_field) but you can write a custom field type extending JFormFieldCalendar or use a 3rd party component like Brent said as JQuery timepicker, mootools datetimepicker... etc

Comment: @vzamanillo I hope that somebody already developed an extension... thanks for pointing that out, though!

Comment: have you tried http://ty2u.com/help/joomla/modules/date-and-time.html ? I thought it's should fulfill your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Datepicker Plugin for Joomla! 
It is a plugin for joomla 2.5 (i cant say about compatibility), that changes the calendar of Joomla default to Mootools Datepicker. Easy to use and customize.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/admin-interface/21332

If you want to see a demo, go to [here](http://aryweb.nl/projects/mootools-datepicker/Test/) (but download it from the previous link)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 2):

As of Joomla 3.7, a time picker is supported from core Joomla. This is documented [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/Calendar_form_field_type).

You use the form field type 'calendar' and set the parameter 'showtime' to true. One possible gotcha is that you must specify the format which Joomla will return the data. By default, the format is '%Y-%m-%d', which doesn't include time, so even if the time picker is there, the selected value wont be sent back to the server. You should use a format such as: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', to include hours and minutes.

Comment: Thank you for this heads-up!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery - http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/timepicker/

There are several plugins to choose from.

Comment: Thanks, I hope to find sth more Joomla-like though, integrating a jQuery-plugin into the Admin-form seems too much to me now.

Answer (score 0):

[10 JQUERY TIME PICKER PLUGINS](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-time-picker-plugins/) Here you have simple datetime picker to a complex one. You can choose one out of them.

I think you don't need a  big complex component to handle a simple datetime picker.